# iBeacon error or bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, ibeacon

I just ran into this issue in iOS Ibeacon. When my app wanted to start monitoring, i get the `Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 4.)"` message. I read that it is not only me. I restart my device and ask permission from the user too and upgrade the ios to 8.2, but still have that issue.
Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried one of the iBeacon monitoring apps from the store?  Do you get the permission prompt when you first run your app?  Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should verify that you both are prompting a user for permission to use location services:

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; 
}
```

And that you have an entry in your plist file with the key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and a string like "This app uses your location to do XXXXX"

If you think you already have the above, you may want to post the details of how you are doing this in your question in case there is a problem.